# How to get refresh token from authorization code and how to get an access token from that refresh token?

Tags: jsp, oauth-2.0, google-admin-sdk

I'm writing a web application where I'm getting an authorization code with which I'm able to get an access token. But this token expires in an hour's time. So how do I get a refresh token from the authorization code and use the same refresh token to get a new access token each time the old one expires?

I'm working with Java and Jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about get access/refresh token from Google. To get a refresh token, you should set access_type=offline when you request the authorization code. You can find details in the [Google OAuth2 web server flow documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer). Alternatively you can choose to use [Google OAuth2 client library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v1) if you don't want to implement the flows by yourself.

Comment: but assigning the access_type=offline, the user is redirected to the consent screen each time he/she logs in. i want the consent screen to be displayed only one time to the user. amid, thanks for the response.

Comment: You only need to ask the user's permission once. After the user grants the permission, you'll receive an authorization code and you can exchange it for a refresh token. To avoid prompting the user every time, you need save the refresh token in a safe storage and use it to get a new access token when the current one is expired.